# Mule 4 : Questions related to Mule 4 project structure and Anypoint Studio

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform

1. What is the difference between "Mule Domain Project" and "Maven
   Parent POM and child projects"?
2. Can we create Multi Module Maven based Mule 4 projects in Anypoint Studio v7.x ? if yes, then please share how.
3. How to fix the project structure in Anypoint Studio for a mule 4 project when it gets corrupted for some reason and the **src/mule/app src/mule/test** folders are not visible?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Domains are a type of Mule Runtime project. Mule applications can depend on one Mule Domains, the domain can share configurations with its applications. Maven parent POM are a Maven concept, totally independent of Mule applications and domains.
2. Anypoint Studio doesn't currently provide any support for Maven multi module projects. It may work or not.
3. Those are not standard Studio 7/Mule 4 directories. As an example Studio projects use src/main/mule and src/test/munit directories, following general Maven conventions. It is not clear exactly what happened to your project, but there doesn't seems to be a general solution for that. You might try to create a new project and copy the old files into the new one.

Comment: Can we create a Mule 4 Domain project and also read it as a parent pom project?  I am of the mind to use a single project where I can aggregate all my maven dependencies and Mule configurations together.

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. A Mule Domain project is a type of project. Parent POM should be something different with a different objective. Keep them separated.